# How do I return to the position I branched from in assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I am using the arm simulator to write a program that to keep it simple for this question blinks the two LEDS in the simulator when one of the blue keys are pressed. my problem is that when I branch from my program to the blinking function it doesn't go back to where I branched from, instead when it finishes the wait loop it just does whatever is written underneath the wait loop

main loop

```
swi SWI_CheckBlue


cmp r0, #0
blne BlinkBoth



BlinkBoth:
    mov r0,#(LEFT_LED|RIGHT_LED)
    swi SWI_SETLED

    ldr r3,=500
    BL Wait

    mov r0,#0
    swi SWI_SETLED


Wait:
    stmfd sp!,{r0-r5,lr}
    ldr r4,=0x00007FFF @mask for 15-bit timer
    SWI SWI_GetTicks @Get start time
    and r1,r0,r4 @adjusted time to 15-bit

Wloop:
    SWI SWI_GetTicks @Get current time
    and r2,r0,r4 @adjusted time to 15-bit
    cmp r2,r1
    blt Roll @rolled above 15 bits
    sub r5,r2,r1 @compute easy elapsed time
    bal CmpLoop
Roll:
    sub r5,r4,r1 @compute rolled elapsed time
    add r5,r5,r2
    CmpLoop:cmp r5,r3 @is elapsed time < delay?
    blt Wloop @Continue with delay
Xwait:
    ldmfd sp!,{r0-r5,pc}
```

Comment: Your `BlinkBoth` function doesn't save LR or jump to it to return, and just falls into `Wait` again.  You have to use instructions to return from functions if that's what you want to happen.

Comment: how do I do that? something like b lr?

Comment: Typically `bx lr` or `mov pc,lr`.

Comment: Also note that a conditional jump (e.g. `blne BlinkBoth`) directly followed by the label you're jumping to is pointless. Even if the jump isn't taken you'll still end up at that label.

Comment: @Michael: It's super-weird but there is a difference: if the jump is not-taken, then it gets there without modifying `lr`.  It's not "pointless" for branch-and-link, but it certainly looks wrong in this case.  And of course you could do the same thing more cheaply with `movle lr, pc` (or `sub lr, pc, #-4` or something because PC points 2 instructions ahead on ARM)

Comment: thanks for the help I will pick this back up tomorrow and update the question once I get it working. right now it jumps back to where it branched from and the program just ends instead of continuing from where it left off.